# What are Prakṣipta? And are they as important as original verses?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, dharma

Why do many people call *Prakṣipta* uncreditable?
Are verse relating the philosophy of existence of one god *Prakṣipta* ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first part of your question. “Prakshipt” according to the Hindi language means — interpolated. interpolation refers to the insertion of something into a text or something else. for example — if i had written an essay in 2018, then added something now — that’s considered an interpolation. often — interpolations cannot be credible.

And, according to [Sanskrit dictionary](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?tran_input=prakSipta&direct=au&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) too, Prakshipta can mean interpolated.

> प्रक्षिप्त    ppp.    prakSipta   cast at     
>  प्रक्षिप्त     ppp.    prakSipta
> thrown at       
>  प्रक्षिप्त     adj.    prakSipta       thrown or cast at       
> प्रक्षिप्त    adj.    prakSipta       thrown forth        
>  प्रक्षिप्त     adj.
> prakSipta       projected       
>  प्रक्षिप्त     adj.
> prakSipta       interpolated        
>  प्रक्षिप्त     adj.    prakSipta       inserted

Comment: HI!! Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) and **specifically** [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)

Comment: In Sanskrit too the word has interpolated as one meaning. I have added a dictionary reference for the same. You can edit the answer more if you're not happy with my edit.